# color and size variation for single line - Altair

Tags: altair

I'm trying to change color and size of a line, basing on attributes variations. I tried with [trail](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/trail_marker.html) because it's the only example i found in [the doc](https://altair-viz.github.io/). 
My test:

```
datas = pd.DataFrame({'num': range(10),
                      'value': [5, 5, 10, 10, 3, 3, 9, 9, 7, 7],
                      'size': [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.9, 0.9, 0.7, 0.7],
                      'otherMarker': ['foo']*2 + ['bar']*2 + ['foo']*2 + ['bar']*2 + ['egg']*2}
alt.Chart(datas).mark_trail.encode(
    x='num',
    y='value',
    size='size:Q',
    color='otherMarker:N')
```

gives me
[image]
instead i'd like
[image]
.
How can i achieve this ?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to achieve that color with a line/trail because assigning a color also means creating a group. I think you would have to carefully add extra point in the data to get that result, you can see some ideas here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844077/override-altairs-default-grouping-for-line-chart

Comment: Thanks for the reply and tip. i tried by resampling my data (my real datas is based on a timeSerie), but the problem is that my values of 'otherMarker' are not continuous, so the grouping always merge the values of the same group by creating weird lines. Actually i'm not able to do this (lack of comptence), so i'll simply do vertical concatenation to show the simultanous variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `impute=alt.ImputeParams(value=None)` will help you avoid that joining. You can also look at the `detail` parameter for this.

```
plt =alt.Chart(datas).mark_trail().encode(
    x='num',
    y=alt.Y('value', 
            impute=alt.ImputeParams(value=None)
        ),
    size='size:Q',
    color='otherMarker:N'
)
plt
```

[image]

A brute force approach to join the lines like the one shown in your image will be

```
# generate a dataframe for the lines connecting different 'otherMarker' types
def get_joining_lines(df):
    ids = datas[(datas['otherMarker']!=datas['otherMarker'].shift(-1))].index.to_list()[0:-1] # remove the last index
    ar = []
    for i in ids:
        temp = datas.loc[[i, i+1]] #adjacent indexes where the change happens
        temp['otherMarker'] = datas.loc[i]['otherMarker'] # change the tag of the last tag to be equal the previous
        ar.append(temp)
    df_temp = pd.concat(ar)
    return(df_temp)

df_temp = get_joining_lines(datas)
edge = alt.Chart(df_temp).mark_trail().encode(
    x='num',
    y=alt.Y('value', impute=alt.ImputeParams(value=None)),
    color='otherMarker:N'
)
edge
```

[image]

The color mapping is different from the initial plot, but this will get resolved when you combine them. If you want, you can hard code the color mapping using `range` and `domain` in the `scale` argument while defining `color`.

Finally, you can layer these two together to get

```
edge+ plt
```

[image]